# Creating Buttons Programmatically in ViewPager instead of in XML

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to have left and right buttons on my views within the ViewPager. On the first view though, I only need a right button and on the last, only a left button. How would I create the buttons programmatically by utilizing ViewPager & PagerAdapter?

It seems that I cannot do it within the instantiateItem of the PagerAdapter, which sucks because I can only use the 'position' parameter in the PagerAdapter code.

This is in my onCreate, where rl is declared globally in the Activity:

```
Button btnLeftClick = new Button(this);
btnLeftClick.setText("&lt&lt");
btnLeftClick.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Button btnRightClick = new Button(this);
btnRightClick.setText("&gt&gt");
btnRightClick.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rl = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.view1, null);
```

This is what I tried to do in my PagerAdapter, but I'm getting NullPointerException:

```
if (position == numViews) {
                rl.addView(btnLeftClick);
}
```

If I instead add the view in onCreate without the if statement, I don't get a NullPointerException.

Any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out from this source: The answer to this is right here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/comment-page-1/#comment-14065

My issue was that I had to refer to the layout that the button was in first in order to use `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if rl is null. The btnLeftClick seems not bad.

Comment: Oh I see, yes it was null. Do you know if I can instantiate and work with buttons within the Adapter?